# rigidbody.velocity is not working smoothly in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d, rigid-bodies

wrote a script to move the player by dragging it, so at first, I moved the player with transform.position and it worked perfectly so I said its time to move it with rigidbody to make it collides with objects,
so I tried rigidbody.velocity but it not moving smoothly. so how to make this works like transform.position?

this is the script:

> ```
> void Update()
> {
>     if(Input.touchCount > 0)
>     {
>        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
>      
>         if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
>         {
>             transform.position = new Vector3(
>             transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedmodifier,
>             transform.position.y,
>             transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedmodifier);
>              
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When using [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) you want to do all physics related stuff in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html). then you probably would not use [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) but set fix positions using [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

You should still get the User input via `Update` though.

I would separate the logic. Something like maybe

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
private Vector3 targetPosition;

private void Start()
{
    targetPosition = transform.position;
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    // since this rigibody is going to be moved via code not Physics it should be kinemtic
    _rigibody.isKinematic = true;
    // in order to smooth the movement
    _rigidbody.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
       Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
     
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * speedmodifier;
            targetPosition += Vector3.forward * touch.deltaPosition.y * speedmodifier;      
        }
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);
}
```

Comment: It's not colliding with objects.